# JupyterNotebook: Attribute Error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = lambda x: x.split(' '))
tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data['Tags'])
```

Output showing attribute error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a1d706a0e2cd> in <module>()
     18 # and learns the vocabulary; second, it transforms our training data
     19 # into feature vectors. The input to fit_transform should be a list of strings.
---> 20 tag_dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(tag_data['Tags'])

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     66     """
     67     if lower:
---> 68         doc = doc.lower()
     69     if accent_function is not None:
     70         doc = accent_function(doc)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Could you please add the output of `type(tag_data['Tags'])`. I guess it is None type isn't it ?

Comment: @Angerato yes it is None type

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Answer (score 1):

*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'* means that, you gave NoneType object to `fit_trainsform` function. Moreover, you can see the description in the error message line 19: *The input to fit_transform should be a list of strings.*

Therefore, the error is your `tag_data['Tags']` variable. It should be a list of strings like that:

```
tag_data['Tags'] = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
```

If it is a pandas dataframe. You can convert it to a list of string with that:

```
tag_data['Tags'].tolist()
```

If it is not, the important point is that, extract strings from tag_data['Tags'] and put them into list.